# I want to extract a particular pattern from a content string: "<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>"

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract "Twitter for iPhone" part from this string.
But I have different values in the place of "Twitter for iPhone" in 1000s of columns in a dataframe. I only need the values after ">" and before "<" from the following set of strings.

I tried df.col.str.extract('(Twitter for iPhone|Twitter for Samsung|Twitter for others)') which extracts only those 'Twitter for iPhone' values but not the others and the rest are filled with NaNs.

Comment: Sounds like a use case for regex or beautiful soup, if you could provide a few example of input and desired output it would help us answer. A straightforward answer would be to just use regex `\>(.*?)\<`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the input is a column with rows having content that look as in the 'content string' of the question and the desired output is just that text between ">" and "<". Using this regex gave me NaNs in all the rows..

Comment: Maybe you want to remove the tags, try `df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'<[^>]*>', '')`

Comment: Still not extracting the desired output.. I am really stuck with the regex expression there. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `col.str.split()` with the regex pattern `r'<|>'` to get a list of the elements in the column and select the one you want (Note that this assumes the entire data element is the string provided)

```
twits=['<a href=”http://twitter.com/download/iphone“ rel=”nofollow“>Twitter for iPhone</a>',
      '<a href=”http://twitter.com/download/iphone“ rel=”nofollow“>Twitter for Samsung</a>',
      '<a href=”http://twitter.com/download/iphone“ rel=”nofollow“>Twitter for Others</a>']

ser=pd.Series([np.random.choice(twits,1)[0] for i in range(10)])

ser.str.split(r'<|>').str[2]

0    Twitter for Samsung
1     Twitter for iPhone
2     Twitter for iPhone
3     Twitter for Others
4     Twitter for iPhone
5     Twitter for Others
6     Twitter for Others
7    Twitter for Samsung
8     Twitter for iPhone
9     Twitter for Others
```

Comment: Awesome.. !! This code worked for me.. Can you please explain the .split function. Is str[2] the third half of the split segments, which has the desired output ?

Comment: `series.str.split()` uses the charatcers you provide to split a string into a list of strings. Then, you are correct, the `.str[2]` selects the element in the list at index `2`. You can always try using different indexers and see what the results are!

Comment: Excellent.. !! Thanks so much for the answer..Yes using different  indexers make us capture whatever part of the split we're interested in.. Makes sense.. :).. Was stuck with this for a long time.. My bad..

Comment: I'm happy to have helped! No need to say "my bad", rather say you learned something new :) If this solved your issue, feel free to accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark

Comment: True.. Learnt new stuff.. :) I already clicked the green checkmark twice but don't see any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing @CMMCD's comment, this code:

```py
import pandas as pd

a = ["""<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>""",
 """<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Cats</a>"""
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['WebLinks'])


df['WebLinks'].str.extract(r"\>(.*?)\<")
```

returns this result:

```
0   Twitter for iPhone
1   Twitter for Cats
```

What's happening is that `r"\>(.*?)\<"` means "regex string that pattern matches for anything between a closing tag (`\>`) and opening tag (`\<`)." I wouldn't recommend getting rid of the tags for this approach.

If this doesn't work, can you post the code that gave you the `nans`?

Comment: Thanks a ton.. !! This code works great.. !!! So (.*?) means any pattern appearing between the tags, be it text, white space ? Does this also work for numbers ?

Comment: the '.' means "match any character except a newline." The '*' generally means "match any number of repetitions of the previous pattern", but when it's followed by a '?', it means "do so n a non-greedy fashion." For the example I've provided, using `r"\>(.*)\<"` will return the same result -- I was just implementing the regex provided by @CMMCD. You can find more information here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation as well as the link.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `df.col.str.extract(pat = '(Twitter for (iPhone|Samsung|others))')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my pattern is similar to "TwitterCats", "Twitter for Cats" etc